# With the intent flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED not getting the app to previous state

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android launcher application which will show my own applications only, starting with login activity.
After login my own custom applications will be shown.
In my custom applications i am providing a home button which will redirect me to my launcher applications previous state.
I am launching the launcher intent as follows

```
   PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("Package name");

    if(intent != null) {

        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

As per these flags the launcher application should be launched with the previous where it was left, but unfortunately i am redirecting to my main activity that is login screen which i don't want.

Am i doing any mistake in launching the activity?

I have declared activities in Manifest as

```
    <activity android:name="LoginManager"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="fios"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale" />
```

I have tested it in android 2.3.3 which is working fine and i am redirecting to launcher previous state,but i am facing problem in android 4.2 devices .